# Login Amazon Music with Robobrowser

Tags: python-3.x, http, http-headers, beautifulsoup, session-cookies

I try to login to AmazonMusic using RoboBrowser.
I got it working with Mechanize by using a script intended for Kodi, but since I want to user Python3 I also need it to work with RoboBrowser.

This is working (Python 2):

```html
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-Agent', userAgent)]
 br.open(urlMain + "/gp/dmusic/marketing/CloudPlayerLaunchPage/ref=dm_dp_mcn_cp")
br.select_form(name="signIn")
br["email"] = email
br["password"] = password
br.addheaders = [
                 ('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'),
                 ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate'),
                 ('Accept-Language', 'de,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6'),
                 ('Cache-Control', 'max-age=0'),
                 ('Connection', 'keep-alive'),
                 ('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
                 ('User-Agent', userAgent),
                 ('Upgrade-Insecure-Requests', '1')]
br.submit()
resp = br.response().read()
```

This is my code for Python 3:

```html
import robobrowser
from requests import Session

session = Session()

browser = robobrowser.RoboBrowser(session=session, history=True)
browser.open("http://www.amazon.de/gp/dmusic/marketing/CloudPlayerLaunchPage/ref=dm_dp_mcn_cp")
loginForm = browser.get_form(id='ap_signin_form')
loginForm['email'] = "a"
loginForm['password'] = "b"

browser.submit_form(loginForm)
#print(browser.parsed)
```

The problem is that I get as answer, that I need to accept cookies.
But how do I do that? I thought the cookies are stored in the session that i pass to the RoboBrowser and are reused for each POST. I also tried without passing a session in the beginning - doesn't make any difference...

What am I doing wrong?
I also tried with MechanicalSoup but got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

There is no User Agent specified

```
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0'
browser = robobrowser.RoboBrowser(session=session, user_agent=user_agent, history=True)
```